# Fallo a la hora de getWritableDatabase(); Android

Tags: android, android-context

Me da un fallo a la hora de establecer la base de datos como escribible en esta linea:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = baseDatos.getWritableDatabase();
```

Android Monitor ERROR:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.iberd.actionvalue, PID: 1918                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iberd.actionvalue/com.example.iberd.actionvalue.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase com.example.iberd.actionvalue.sqlite.BaseDatosValue.getWritableDatabase()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase com.example.iberd.actionvalue.sqlite.BaseDatosValue.getWritableDatabase()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.iberd.actionvalue.sqlite.OperacionesBaseDatos.getDb(OperacionesBaseDatos.java:36)
                                                                             at com.example.iberd.actionvalue.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

En la clase Main añado los elementos al objeto y sobrecargo el método `insertarCartera()` de la clase OperacionesBaseDatos:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

OperacionesBaseDatos bdOperaciones = new OperacionesBaseDatos();

// Agregamos un método en MainActivity, los métodos para obtener una instancia de la misma y sea y usado como contexto:
 public static MainActivity thisActivity;

 public MainActivity() {
 thisActivity = this;
 }

 public static MainActivity getInstance() {
 return thisActivity;
 }

static final String[] TITULOS_BTN =
        new String[]{"INTEL (INTC)", "PFIZER (PFE)", "CISCO (CSCO)", "GENERAL ELECTRIC (GE)",
                "ORACLE (ORCL)", "SUNWORKS (SUNW)", "IBM (IBM)", "HP (HPQ)", "QUALCOMM (QCOM)",
                "AMAZON (AMZN)", "MICROSOFT (MSFT)", "APPLE (AAPL)", "NASDAQ (NDAQ)", "ORO (GC=F)", "PETROLEO (CL=F)"};

public ListView lvListaDeBotones;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvListaDeBotones = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListaDeBotones);
    MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, TITULOS_BTN);
    lvListaDeBotones.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Puede que sobre
    lvListaDeBotones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Aquí puedes capturar en on Click de la vista que se crea en general.
        }
    });

    Button btnIbex = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noticiasButton);

    btnIbex.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), bdPruebaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


     Cartera carteraObj = new Cartera();
     carteraObj.setId_valor(4);
     carteraObj.setPrecio(Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(7777.77)));
     carteraObj.setFcompra("2017-02-12 12:12:12.475");
     carteraObj.setCantidad(7);

     bdOperaciones.insertarCartera(carteraObj);

}
}
```

Clase OperacionesBaseDatos:

```
public class OperacionesBaseDatos {

private static BaseDatosValue baseDatos;
private static OperacionesBaseDatos instancia;

public static OperacionesBaseDatos obtenerInstancia() {
    return obtenerInstancia(MainActivity.getInstance());
}

public static OperacionesBaseDatos obtenerInstancia(Context contexto) {
    if (baseDatos == null) {
        baseDatos = new BaseDatosValue(contexto);
    }
    return instancia;
}

public void insertarCartera(Cartera cartera) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = baseDatos.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put(MetadatosDB.Carteras.ID_VALOR, cartera.getId_valor());
    valores.put(MetadatosDB.Carteras.PRECIO, cartera.getPrecio());
    valores.put(MetadatosDB.Carteras.FCOMPRA, cartera.getFcompra());
    valores.put(MetadatosDB.Carteras.CANTIDAD, cartera.getCantidad());

    db.insertOrThrow(BaseDatosValue.Tablas.CARTERA, null, valores);

    db.close();
}
}
```

Comment: El fallo está en que no le pasas el `Context`. El primer trozo de código en el que llamas a OperacionesBaseDatos donde está? ¿En un Activity? ¿En una clase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como esta actualmente tu código, es necesario usar el método que recibe el contexto para obtener la instancia de la BD:

```
OperacionesBaseDatos bdOperaciones = new OperacionesBaseDatos(getApplicationContext());
```

---

Lo que se realiza en este caso para asegurar obtener una instancia de la base de datos al llamar un método que no recibe el contexto, es es agregar un método en MainActivity los métodos para obtener una instancia de la misma y sea y usado como contexto:

```
public static MainActivity thisActivity;

public MainActivity() {
    thisActivity = this;
}

public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return thisActivity;
}
```

Esto para asegurar que ambos métodos funcionen y obtengan la instancia de la BD:

```
public static OperacionesBaseDatos obtenerInstancia() {
   return obtenerInstancia(MainActivity.getIntance());
}

public static OperacionesBaseDatos obtenerInstancia(Context contexto) {
    if (baseDatos == null) {
        baseDatos = new BaseDatosValue(contexto);
    }
    return instancia;
}
```

de esta forma podrás  realizar sin problema lo que deseas:

```
OperacionesBaseDatos bdOperaciones = new OperacionesBaseDatos();
```

Comment: Estoy siendo incapaz de solucionarlo, en cuanto al context parece ser que si lo he solucionado aun que ahora me sigue dando el mismo fallo y nose si de verdad solucione el problema o que ahora he desencadenado otra falla a la que aun no habia llegado. O que ahora debo pasarle el context a **SQLiteDatabase db = baseDatos.getWritableDatabase();** . Un saludo @Jorgesys

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con la situacion actual

Comment: problema solucionado me faltaba poner **baseDatosHelper = new BaseDatosValue(MainActivity.getInstance());** en la clase OperacionesBaseDatos

Answer (score 1):

El error está en que estás inicializando `OperacionesBaseDatos` a través del constructor en vez de la instancia entonces `baseDatos` es nulo, para inicializarlo:

```
Context contexto = this; // Si estás en un Activity
OperacionesBaseDatos bdOperaciones = OperacionesBaseDatos.obtenerInstancia(contexto);
```

Al usar el patrón `Singleton` el constructor suele hacerse privado ya que sólo debería ser accesible a través de la propia clase utilizando el método que obtiene la instancia.

Para obtener el contexto, si estás en un Activity puedes usar `this` (la propia Activity), si estás en un Fragment puedes pasarle el del Activity con `getActivity()`. Si estás en una clase deberás pasárselo a través del método desde el lugar en que lo llamas

Answer (score 1):

La variable `baseDatos` nunca se inicializa. Para ello  puedes poner en el constructor esto:

```
public OperacionesBaseDatos(Context contexto) {
    if (baseDatos == null) {
        baseDatos = new BaseDatosValue(contexto);
    }
    return instancia;
}
```

A la hora de inicializar la clase haz lo siguiente:

```
OperacionesBaseDatos bdOperaciones = new OperacionesBaseDatos(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

Ojo, tu constructor recibe como parametro un `Context` y tu no lo envias, por lo tanto tu objeto `BaseDatosValue` no esta inicializado en ningun momento.

Cuando llames a tu base de datos debes enviarlo, si estas desde un `Activity`

```
OperacionesBaseDatos bdOperaciones = new OperacionesBaseDatos(getContext());
bdOperaciones.insertarCartera(carteraObj);
```